# How can I use Kik on a Win7Pro PC without a phone or a Google account, for example perhaps with a Windows Phone emulator?

Tags: instant-messaging, windows-phone

How can I use the instant messenger program Kik - most commonly installed on smartphones and other mobile devices - on a laptop or desktop running Win7Pro, without a phone being involved and without needing any kind of Google account?

The two ways of using Kik from my laptop that I have so far found are both inadequate, or at least I do not how to tweak them to make them meet the requirements.

The first is to install on my laptop the Bluestacks emulator of Google's Android operating system, and then to run Kik on it. Unfortunately to run Kik on Bluestacks requires (or at least I have not found a way to avoid) having a Google Play account.

The second is to run Bluestacks on Manymo, the online emulator of Google's Android OS. Unfortunately, using Kik on Manymo similarly requires a Google Play account.

I realise Kik was made for use on a mobile OS, but it is supposed to be cross-platform where mobile OSes are concerned, and therefore not to be tied into Google's mobile OS - or, as far as I know, into any other software supplied by Google or any procedure prescribed by that company, such as giving it personal information - so I am optimistic that someone will be able to advise on what I am asking for here.

I notice that Microsoft have made a [Windows Phone emulator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/ff402563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), so there might be a way to get Kik to work on this without dealing with Google. I couldn't find anything online about this, though.

Comment: Have you tried [**downloading the current Kik version as an APK**](https://www.google.de/search?num=30&site=&source=hp&q=kik++10.5.0.6447&oq=kik++10.5.0.6447&gs_l=hp.3...2975.18685.0.19053.8.8.0.0.0.0.110.579.7j1.8.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..0.7.517...0j0i3j46i3j0i3i46j0i10j0i22i30j0i22i10i30.dKxPc4mkJts) and [**installing it on bluestack**](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42983/how-can-i-install-apk-file-on-bluestacks-app-player)

Comment: No, because of what I say in the third paragraph.

Comment: Google has fairly extensive privacy settings that you can use to disable just about any tracking it does.  You can make an account just for Kik and then go to privacy.google.com while logged in and disable everything.  You are not safer hiding from Google and then not hiding from Kik.  Also cross-platform doesn't mean a release on a specific platform won't use platform-specific APIs, such as the ones that integrate with Google's accounts.

Comment: The best way not to be tracked by a company is not to install any of its software on your equipment or log in to its server from your equipment.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, Kik isn't available on PC or Mac. You can find a version of Kik for your Windows 7 PC on the sites like "Bluestacks" but they aren't authorized by Kik and may put your personal information at risk. For more info, you may refer to this link: https://kikinteractive.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/217681438-Is-there-a-version-of-Kik-for-my-computer-

Comment: It is available to run on software that runs on a Windows PC (the Bluestacks emulator of Google's Android) or that can be used online from a Windows PC (the Manymo emulator, also of Google's Android), and the company Kik has no problem with the use of its software on these platforms so authorisation is not an issue. But I have only found ways of using it on my laptop that require either using a phone or taking the information risk of having a Google account. I will amend the question to say something about what I already know.