# Can the Kik Messenger be installed on a laptop running on Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit OS?

Tags: windows-10, installation, chat, instant-messaging, messaging

I live in India an in the last month I bought Lenovo laptop fitted with x64-based Intel 6th Generation Core i5 Processor.

This laptop came pre-installed with the Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit OS.

I want to install [Kik Messenger](https://www.kik.com) on this laptop but I am not able to find out the exact, reliable and easy way to do it and use it on my new machine.

Would someone please let me know if Kik Messenger can be installed and runon my new machine.

If yes, how? If no, why?

Comment: [kik isn't available for Windows 10 PC](http://superuser.com/a/1082649/270195)

Comment: @pun:Does that mean I can't use Kik Messenger on my new machine?

Comment: @JSLover You can but not by regular means. You would need to install Bluestacks or something like it. Read the answer from the link I posted above

Comment: Why not the compatability mode for kik to windows 8 or 7...